# Rewriting query string to another query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to take search urls that are passed to my site like this:

```
 /index.php?keyword=47174&Search=Search&Itemid=1&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse
```

and change them into this:

```
 /catalogsearch/result/?q=47174
```

I need to take the value after "keyword=" ignore everything after the & sign and give it to the second url after the ?q=

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /catalogsearch/result/ [L]
```

This however, prints keyword= at the end of the url as well, does not print the q= or clean everything after the &

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. What I do not understand is how %1 references only the ([^&]+) , at any rate it worked. Thank you

Comment: It references the first group of brackets. If you had two groups of brackets you could use %1 and %2.

Answer (score 1):

You will want your RewriteRule something like:

```
RewriteRule keyword=([0-9a-zA-Z_]+) /catalogsearch/result/?q=%1 [L]
```

Everything inside the parenthesis will replace the `%1` on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L]
                                               ^^^^^
```

where `$1` is the back reference to the captured group 1 (here.. value of keyword)